# Expanding a periodic function into a Fourier series

Tags: fourier-series

[image]

The solutions say that $$b_n=-\frac{4}{n\pi}$$ but I keep getting $$b_n=-\frac{2}{n\pi}$$

I checked with Wolfram Alpha and it seems that my integrals are right. Is this just a mistake in the solutions? What is the right answer for $b_n$?

Steps:
$$
b_n=\frac{1}{2}\left[\int_{-2}^{0}2\sin\left(\frac{n\cdot\pi\cdot x}{2}\right)dx+\int_{0}^{2}x\sin\left(\frac{n\cdot\pi\cdot x}{2}\right)dx\right]
\\2b_n=\frac{4[(-1)^n-1]}{n\cdot\pi}+\frac{-4\cos(n\cdot\pi)}{n\cdot\pi}
\\b_n=\frac{-2}{n\pi}
$$

Comment: The factor of $2$ suggests you used the wrong normalisation factor, $\frac{1}{L}$ instead of $\frac{2}{L}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I'm not sure what you mean so I've inserted my attempt into the question.

Comment: Hmm, looks right. Then I guess the solution is wrong.

Comment: I think those dashed red lines are there for a reason. Namely, that's should be your period, not actual least period.

Comment: @Kaster: Ah. That probably explains it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct: the sine part of the Fourier series of this function is indeed
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{-2}{\pi n}\sin \frac{\pi n x}{2} \tag{1}$$
One way to double-check is to simply plot a partial sum, as I did below. The sine part of the Fourier series of $f$ converges to $\frac12(f(x)-f(-x))$, the odd part of $f$. (The cosine part of the Fourier series   converges to $\frac12(f(x)+f(-x))$, the even part of $f$.) For this function, $\frac12(f(x)-f(-x))$ rises with constant slope from $-1 $ to $1$ on the interval $(0,4)$; it is periodic with  period $4$. The sum in (1) matches this:

[image]

Concerning Kaster's comment: taking two periods instead of one does not change the Fourier series of a function, except maybe in notation. You would get 
$$\sum_{n \text{ even}}  \frac{-4}{\pi n}\sin \frac{\pi n x}{4} \tag{2}$$
which is of course the same as (1). Maybe (2) is what the solution author had in mind.

General remark: when discussing coefficients, it is a good idea to say what function the coefficient is attached to. Your textbook's author may decide that $b_n$ always goes with [something], but other  people don't have to share that convention.